# Href issue in Jsp using Liferay?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I need to know about href usage in jsp using life-ray. Please see the below code once.

main.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="portlet" uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />


<portlet:renderURL var="homeURL">
       <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="WEB-INF/jsp/Login.jsp" />
 </portlet:renderURL>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<nav>

    <div class="navHeader"><a href="<%=homeURL.toString() %>"> Home </a></div><br>

    <div class="navHeader">Faqs</div><br>

</nav>

<section>
***** Mian page ******
</section

</body>
</html>
```

The above href was not working.I am new to liferay.so please suggest me what to do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/951277 - I think you have more chances to find answers about Lifray there

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with your demo code:

Make sure your portlet actually implements Liferay's MVCPortlet if you want to use the renderparameter jspPage. Also, jspPage is deprecated, you should rather use mvcPath, but the semantics is the same. Try for yourself if it's actually deprecated or already removed (this might then be the reason for your problems)

And finally: Portlets are not supposed to have `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` elements. These are generated by the theme, not by the individual portlets.

If this doesn't help, you might want to specify what "href wasn't working" means: e.g. what does the link point to, what gets shown when you click the link.